# How to count the number of different levels in an int vector in R?

Tags: r, aggregate

I am new to programming in R and playing around till I get comfortable. I want to know how can I use aggregate function to know the counts of different levels of an integer vector, like the one below:

```
library(caret)
library(kernlab)
data(spam)
folds <- createFolds(y=spam$type,k=10,list=FALSE,returnTrain=TRUE)
aggregate(folds,FUN=length)
```

I can do this by converting folds into a data.frame and then using dplyr package and using mutate to count using function n(). But that's too long. I found aggregate does the same thing but I am struggling with the syntax. I am asking this because I have a very gut feeling that this would be useful and pre-cursory steps counting rows at different levels of any kinds of vector. Any help would be great.

Comment: Just do `table(folds)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do

`table(variable)`

That will give you a count of each level of the variable